# 3D boxes in perspective

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3d

I am trying to draw 3D boxes in perspective, but with no success. The intention is to have several boxes with different sizes on top of each other, like this:

[image]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\simplecuboid[5]{%
    \draw[fill=#5!80!white]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#4) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray!50!white]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#4) -- cycle;
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view, perspective={p={(20,15,0)},q={(0,20,0)}}]
    \simplecuboid{6}{12}{.2}{0}{gray}
    \simplecuboid{6}{12}{.2}{.2}{white}
    \simplecuboid{6}{10}{.2}{.4}{red}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You are already there. Check out `[opacity=0.7]`.  And perhaps `:x=-#1` instead of `:x=#1`

Comment: Can you please add a screeshot, the drawing your posted code creates?

Answer (score 4):

The `[opacity=.xx]` idea came from ***Symbol 1***'s comment of the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647373/260996). I modified some numbers.
Not sure why you need ONLY one layer of the top box to be red. I just keep your idea as the following. Hope it helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\simplecuboid[5]{%
    \draw[fill=#5!80!white,opacity=0.5]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.3]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#4) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray!50!white,opacity=0.7]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#4) -- cycle;
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view, perspective={p={(20,15,0)},q={(0,20,0)}}]
    \simplecuboid{6}{12}{.2}{0}{gray}
    \simplecuboid{6}{12}{.2}{.2}{white}
    \simplecuboid{6}{10}{.2}{.4}{red!80!white}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screeshot, the drawing your posted code creates?

Comment: @MS-SPO please see the update.

Comment: Hi @MattD626 thank you for your contribution. The "steps" in your solution faces twards the back and I need it to face twards the front. I mean, the way the ```perspective``` tikz library was developd has the ```x``` and ```y``` axis pointing into the page, causing the steps to be seen from backwards.

Comment: @Brasil, thank you for pointing it out. Your new output is better. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

I got it:

**Edit:** use `line join=round` argument of `\draw` as suggested by `@SandyG` (thank you very much!) to improve corners.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\simplecuboid[6]{% x = #1, y = #2, z = #3, h = #4, color = #5, fill opacity = #6
    %--> Bottom
    \draw[thin, fill=#5, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            % --(tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#4)
            % --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#4)
            % --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#4)
            % --cycle
        ;
    %--> Left
    \draw[thin, fill=#5!60!white, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#4)
            --cycle
            ;
    %--> Right
    \draw[thin, fill=#5!60!white, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            --cycle
        ;
    %--> Back
    \draw[thin, fill=#5!45!white, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#4)
            --cycle
            ;
    %--> Front
    \draw[thin, fill=#5!45!white, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            --(tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            --cycle
        ;
    %--> Top
    \draw[thin, fill=#5!30!white, fill opacity=#6, line join=round]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3+#4)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3+#4)
            --cycle
            ;
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={140}{12}, perspective={p={(-30,0,0)},q={(0,-30,0)}}, scale=0.4]
    \simplecuboid{6}{12.0}{.2}{0.0}{black}{1}
    \simplecuboid{6}{11.5}{.2}{0.2}{white}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{11.0}{.2}{0.4}{red}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{11.0}{.2}{0.6}{red}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{10.5}{.2}{0.8}{white}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{10.0}{.2}{1.0}{red}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{10.0}{.2}{1.2}{red}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{09.5}{.2}{1.4}{white}{.8}
    \simplecuboid{6}{09.0}{.2}{1.6}{blue}{.8}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest adding `line join=round` to your `tikzpicture` to improve the corners.

Comment: Thank  you very much for the suggestion @SandyG!